# Javascript change variable name in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript

I am looking to change a variable name from an object within a foreach loop

```
var days = ['monday','tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];

days.forEach(function(day, index){

  // agency.openingHours.monday.opening; // replace monday to day
  // here I want instead of monday to have the day, agency.openingHours.day.opening



})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var days = ['monday','tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];

days.forEach(function(day){
  console.log(agency.openingHours[day].opening)

})
```

You are changing not a *variable* name, and not changing. You loop through keys of `openingHours` object. This would be more correct

Comment: I tried that but it says cannot find 'opening' of undefined.

Comment: This means that one `day` is missing in openingHours object. console.log it to see which

Comment: You're right! There was an misspelled variable in the database I tried instead of agency.openingHours['monday'].opening and it's working

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev could you clarify _"You are changing not a variable name, and not changing."_

Comment: You are welcome! @Andy "You are changing not a variable name, and not changing." is the worse version of "You are not changing anything, you are looping through keys of `openingHours` object"

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev, it reads like a Japanese Koan :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use days.map() instead of days.forEach because map() returns a new array.

Refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

`agency.openingHours[day].opening` - it's the same as accessing object properties with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) (`agency.openingHours['Monday'].opening`) except you don't quote the variable.

```js
var days = ['monday','tuesday', 'wednesday'];

const agency = {
  openingHours: {
    monday: { opening: '0900' },
    tuesday: { opening: '0500' },
    wednesday: { opening: '1000' }
  }
}

days.forEach(function(day, index) {
  console.log(agency.openingHours[day].opening);
});
```

Comment: Thank Andy! That's completely right!